# Verilog Parameterized macro usage

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

I am trying to use parameterized macros in Verilog to dynamically change the master module of instances through macro names as tried below.

```
`define AND_CELL(tech) ``tech``_2oi1_1x 

`define TECH_1 tech1
`define TECH_2 tech2

module top(in1, in2, in3, in4, out_x);
  input in1, in2, in3, in4;
  output out_x;
  wire t1_c, t2_c;

  `AND_CELL(`TECH_1) u1(.a(in1), .b(in2), .x(t1_c));
  `AND_CELL(`TECH_2) u2(.a(in3), .b(in4), .x(t2_c));

  assign out_x = t1_c | t2_c ;
endmodule

module tech1_2oi1_1x(a, b, x);
  input a, b;
  output x;
  assign x = a & b;
endmodule

module tech2_2oi1_1x(a, b, x);
  input a, b;
  output x;
  assign x = a & b;
endmodule
```

The intent here to have the top module to have two different AND gates based on the TECH_1 and TECH_2 macro values.

My attempt gives syntax error while compiling the RTL, as below:

> error: invalid module item.

Can someone help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: I corrected the example code to have input/output definitions. I still get compile errors at instantiation lines.

Comment: @Qiu: So is it not driven by Verilog 2001 LRM?

Comment: @Qui: Does it compile in EDA Synthesis tool?

Comment: More discussion on this question asked here: https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/verilog-parameterized-macro-usage-rtl

Answer (score 1):

``` `` ``` a SysemVerilog feature. Is is not described in any Verilog LRM (I checked IEEE Std 1364-2001 and IEEE Std 1364-2005), therefore a Verilog Simulator does not need to support it.

Modern Verolog simulators do support SystemVerilog. Simply changing the file extension from `.v` to `.sv` should enables SystemVerilog support for that file. Many simulators also have a `-sv` compiler option, but be warned this makes all Verilog files treated as SystemVerilog (only a problem if there are variable names that are now SV keywords).

The [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) as good examples of using ``` `` ``` in § 22.5.1 *`define*

Comment: How else can I make it work in pure Verilog 2001 format? Any other alternative way for enabling this feature? I cannot use -sv switch to treat this RTL as .sv.

Comment: You could use embedded Perl/Ruby/Python which I mentioned in answers to similar questions: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527839/1959732), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18025864/1959732), & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20625785/1959732). This will require a running the Perl/Ruby/Python script to generate the .v file before compiling with the simulator.